# Full text search matching a specific position in a sentence

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

```
SELECT 'Three little birds are sitting on a tree'::tsvector @@ to_tsquery('simple','birds');
```

Can I modify in a query in a way that I define a specific position in a sentence that the searched term must meet?

In this example, 'birds' is in the third position of the sentence so can I modify the constraint in a way that it returns true only if the match is found at the position given, like

```
to_tsquery2('simple','birds',3) // => true
```

while

```
to_tsquery2('simple','birds',5)  // => false
```

Comment: `to_tsvector('Three little birds are sitting on a tree')` will show you that. But I don't know if you can actually query the position

Answer (score 1):

There are no provisions for that in PostgreSQL full text search.

But you could prepend a “marker” to the text and abuse a phrase search:

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple',
                   'quagga '
                      || 'Three little birds are sitting on a tree'
       )
    @@ to_tsquery('simple',
                  'quagga <3> ' || 'birds'
       );

 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

The phrase `a <3> b` matches a sentence that contains `a` and `b` with two works in between.

You'll have to use a `quagga` that does not appear anywhere in your text.